# Gulp Watch with Dependencies and Callback

Tags: gulp

The signature for gulp-watch is

```
watch(glob, [options, callback])
```

However, it seems like you can either have a callback or options but not both. What I am trying to do is:

```
gulp.watch('*.js',['someTask','anotherTask'],function(event){...});
```

It executes the dependent tasks 'someTask' and 'anotherTask' but does not execute the callback.  You can have a callback:

```
gulp.watch('*.js',function(event){...});
```

Or you can execute dependencies:

```
gulp.watch('*.js',['someTask','anotherTask']);
```

But I cannot get it to execute dependent tasks and give me a callback.

Comment: Note: `gulp.watch` is part of gulp, `gulp-watch` is a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gulp.watch('*.js',function(event){gulp.run('someTask','anotherTask')});
```

Comment: [`gulp.run` has been deprecated](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/199). [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826418/gulp-run-alternative) for alternatives.